# How can blockchains like Steem store large amounts of content?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, cryptocurrency, steemit

How can blockchains like Steem store large amounts of content, considering the fact that it's expensive to store data on blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

i'm working on a project that stores only the HASH of a file on a blockchain... AND the file is stored on a Decentralized Storage Platform like Storj or Maid...

Whenever someone wants to access a content... say on a Website on MAID, that content is fetched from the Maid Storage Network, compared with the HASH on the Blockchain and then presented to the user...

In that way, you can AGREE that the content is TRUE, because the HASH is on the Blockchain (in case you don't know, it's almost impossible to forge a HASH from a Specific Source, without the EXACT source)

You don't need to store the whole data on the blockchain, that's pointless and performance wise unproductive! Remember Blockchains exist for consensus on a specific TRUE, if you can prove that a data OUTSIDE is still the same as first entered... then you're good to go!

(You can always store everything there tho.... just not efficient)